# Django - Ajax POST error 403 (Forbidden) and 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: python, django

I'm using Ajax to post data. It threw the error 403 (Forbidden), then I added `@csrf_exempt` to my view. Afterwards, error 500 (Internal Server Error) occurred.
 I've tried different like following the [docuement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.1/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) to add extra code and imported it to the template. I'm struggling to fix these two problem. One's gone then the other occurs.

Also the view works fine using `action` attribute rather than Ajax. So I don't it's the problem of the view I reckon.

**detail.html:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "cart:add_to_cart" %}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (response_data) {
                    alert('second alert');
                    $("#cartButton").text("Cart" + "(" + response_data.quantity + ")");
                },
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="quantity">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="bookID" value=" {{ book.id }} " hidden>
    <button id="add" type="submit"> Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

Once I added `@csrf_exempt`, error 500 came out.

**cart/views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_books(request):
    print('submitted')
    c = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        q = request.POST.get('quantity', )
        book_id = request.POST.get('bookID', )

        the_id = int(book_id)
        the_quantity = int(q)
        b = Book.objects.get(id=the_id)
        c = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
        title = b.title

        book = BooksInCart.objects.filter(cart=c).filter(book__title=title)
        if book:
            book_in_cart = book.get(book__title=title)
            book_in_cart.quantity += the_quantity
            book_in_cart.save()
        else:
            book_in_cart = BooksInCart.objects.create(cart=c, book=b, quantity=the_quantity)
            book_in_cart.save()

        response_data = {
            'quantity': BooksInCart.objects.filter(cart=c).aggregate(item_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['item_quantity']
        }
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

**part of the error info:**

```
"ValueError at /cart/add_books/↵invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''↵↵Request Method: POST↵Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add_books/↵Django Version: 2.1
```

Comment: `ValueError at /cart/add_books/↵invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: Without your code, we can't debug ...

Comment: @Zulu sorry about that, added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q = request.POST.get('quantity', ) # <--- this or
book_id = request.POST.get('bookID', ) # <---- this is coming back as an empty string
# The below code is causing an error because the above code isn't finding anything
# And it is returning to you an empty string, which it cannot convert to an int()
the_id = int(book_id)
the_quantity = int(q)
```

You need to make sure that there is a value coming back in your POST request otherwise, you'll continue to have the problem of the empty string.  If you are requiring that value, you could require that value before the user can POST the form or you could throw an error in the validation on the server.

Comment: I did try this, then `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: That means you're getting some value that is a NoneType and trying to cast it to an int.  It would be as if you were saying `int(None)`.  You need to figure out where the incorrect value is coming from.  What you're doing now is allowing the POST request to come in with a type that isn't valid.  The POST request isn't finding the values you're looking for, so there is nothing to cast to an int.

Comment: yes I know it means `int(None)`, but I can't see the problem. I set the name for the `<input> tag and `<select>` tag, then the `POST` method should be able to find them

Comment: Well, one thing from your JS, it looks like you are passing a dataType field, but it doesn't look like you're actually passing the data field.

Comment: I changed to this `q = request.POST.get('quantity', '')
        book_id = request.POST.get('bookID', '')`, but how can I slice them, just get the first element of each. I used `the_id = int(book_id[0])`, it says `IndexError: string index out of range
`

Comment: That means that there isn't anything coming back still.  You're trying to slice the empty string, which you can't do.  I think you're problem is the jQuery that you wrote.  It looks like from above that you're not actually sending data with your form.  In you're ajax POST, you're missing the field `data: ...some data here...`.